# Cannot find LTR backups for Azure SQL Database after the server is deleted

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, backup, restore

I have set up LTR for an Azure SQL Database and running the Get-AzSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionBackup -Location northeurope I can see that I have one backup.

[image]

After I have deleted the SQL Server and running Get-AzSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionBackup -Location northeurope again, I can't see the LTR backup. According to https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6443/how-to-restore-azure-sql-ltr-backup-after-azure-sql-instance-deleted/ this should be possible.

So what am I doing wrong?

SKU is Basic and DTU i 5...

Comment: can you share the error if you are facing any

Comment: No error. It's just that when you run the command it does not show the LTR backups. Just nothing :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your scenario in my environment, and it worked successfully.

**Here, LTR backups when server exists:**

[image]

**Here, LTR backups when server is deleted:**

[image]

As you are not getting any error and when you run the command it does not show the LTR backups. **It happens when the LTR is getting deleted after its retention period** in this case you don't get any error, and nothing cones after command execution. please once check your retention policy.

Comment: What sku did you use? And what was the LTR settings? I tried 4 Weeks as we do not need to save for a long time. Just have the extra security if the server happens to get deleted. I also run the Get-AzSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionBackup more or less immediately after the server was removed, so I should have been able to see some backups...